# Hibernate: OneToMany Association not working Unknown entity error

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the following error when I am trying to create a one-to-many association

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag
```

Here is where the code to create the association is run

```
public void assignDoctorSpecialty(Doctor doctor, Specialty specialty) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    doctor.setSpecialty(specialty);

    List<Doctor> doctors = specialty.getDoctors();
    doctors.add(doctor);

    session.save(doctors);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

Here is my **Doctor** class

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="DOCTOR_INFO")
@NamedQueries (
    {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Doctor.getAll", query = "from Doctor"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Doctor.findByName", query = "from Doctor where name = :name")
    }
)
public class Doctor implements Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Specialty specialty; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(unique=true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST) 
    @JoinColumn(name="specialty_id") 
    public Specialty getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    public void setSpecialty(Specialty specialty) {
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }
}
```

Here is my **Specialty** class

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="SPECIALTY_INFO")
@NamedQueries (
    {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Specialty.getAll", query = "from Specialty"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Specialty.findByName", query = "from Specialty where name = :name")
    }
)
public class Specialty {
    private List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(unique=true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="specialty", targetEntity = Doctor.class, 
             fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST) 
    public List<Doctor> getDoctors() {
        return doctors;
    }
    public void setDoctors(List<Doctor> doctors) {
        this.doctors = doctors;
    }    

}
```

**EDIT**

If I save the `Doctor` object directly, instead of trying to indirectly save it through Cascade saving the `Specialty` doctor list, it throws no error. However, when I go into my database, `specialty_id` of the `Doctor` table is not set.

Comment: try with CascadeType.ALL

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to persist a collection of objects using the `save(..)` method. Try the following code:

```
public void assignDoctorSpecialty(Doctor doctor, Specialty specialty) {

    [...]

    for (Doctor d : doctors) {
         session.save(d);
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: if I change `session.save(doctors);` to `session.save(doctor);` there is no error. however, when I go into my database `specialty_id` of the `Doctor` table is empty. Every example I see of one to many relationships save the `many` in order to save the `one`.

Comment: Add the `@Cascade` hibernate annotation and enable `CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE`.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the answer. The reason this happens is because I try to `save` an object that was already saved in the database. All I had to do was replace `session.save(doctor)` with `session.saveOrUpdate(doctor)`.

Comment: That may have fixed it for you, but I think this really came about because you were trying to persist a list rather than its individual entities.